# JSON POST call in Python not working

Tags: python, json, rest, post

I am new to python & POST message.

I am trying to call an API with JSON POST message and expecting a JSON response but my initial code not able to make the call as required .

**using the URL,Headers & Postdata in chrome browser POST extension works fine.**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
import json

url = 'http://xxxxx:111/batches'
postdata = {
    "active": "true",
    "size": "2",
    "ctr": {
        "user": "Admin",
        "id": "1234"}}

#headers = {'content-type': 'application/json',
                         #'Authorization': 'Basic xyz879jjkhhnm',
                         #'Accept-Encoding': '0'}
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic xyz879jjkhhnm', 'Accept-Encoding': '0'}
print headers

post_call = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(postdata))
print post_call, "POST call"

print post_call.text, "TEXT"
print post_call.content, "CONTENT"

post_call.status_code, "STATUS CODE"


Error:
{'Accept-Encoding': '0', 'Authorization': 'Basic xyz879jjkhhnm'}
<Response [500]> POST call
[{"code":"server_error","description":"com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body reader for Java class com.hide.cpn.rest.v1.entity.CouponCodeBatchResourceEntity, 
and Java type class com.hide.cpn.rest.v1.entity.CouponCodeBatchResourceEntity, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.
\nThe registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:\napplication/octet-stream ->\n  
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider\n  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider\n  
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider\n  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider\n  
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider\n*/* ->\n  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider\n  
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider\n  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider\n  
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider\n  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider\n  
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider\n  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General\n  
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider\n  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider\n  
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader\n  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader\n  
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader\n  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General\n  
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General\n  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General\n  
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General\n  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader\n  
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General\n  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General\n  
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy\n","errorValues":null}] TEXT


**Edit:1 (changing Headers seems to get ridoff Java error now ,but getting below error now)**

headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic xyz879jjkhhnm', 'Accept-Encoding': '0', 'content-type': 'application/json'}

New error:
{'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Encoding': '0', 'Authorization': 'Basic xyz879jjkhhnm'}
<Response [400]> POST call
[{"code":"invalid_attribute_of_request","description":"Attribute value type is not Integer. actual value = (\"2\")","errorValues":null,"field":"size"}] TEXT
[{"code":"invalid_attribute_of_request","description":"Attribute value type is not Integer. actual value = (\"2\")","errorValues":null,"field":"size"}] CONTENT
```

Comment: You're getting a 500 error, suggesting there's something broken in your code when this tries to execute. The error response suggests that it recognizes the input as a specific Java class type but doesn't have a message body reader compatible with it. I would follow this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,as per the latest change Header change in (EDIT 1) i had to remove the double quotes from post data "SIZE",that solved my error.

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic xyz879jjkhhnm', 'Accept-Encoding': '0', 'content-type': 'application/json'}


    postdata = {
        "active": "true",
        "size": "2", --> Changed to "size": 2,
        "ctr": {
            "user": "Admin",
            "id": "1234"}}
```

Comment: In your original you didn't have the content-type header you have here.

Comment: right ,that's the the changes I have to make to avoid java error and then changing size to an integer